# Why is the output of df.where() different from df.loc[]?

Tags: python, pandas, where-clause

I am trying to find Total not less than 580 in the table Pokemon

```
import numpy as np #<1>
import pandas as pd #<2>
Pokemon = pd.read_csv('data/Pokemon.csv') #<3>

Pokemon.where(Pokemon['Total']>=580.).dropna().shape #<4>
Pokemon.loc[Pokemon['Total']>=580].shape #<5>
```

Line 4 outputs (78, 13) while line 5 gives (113, 13). What seems to be the problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EakCh.png)The table is attached in this image

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Pokemon.where(Pokemon['Total']>=580.).dropna().shape

After finding all the rows whose `Total >= 580` it drops the rows which have `NaN` values.

> Pokemon.loc[Pokemon['Total']>=580].shape

It finds  all the rows whose `Total >= 580`

So if there are NaNs in the table, first one will have less rows compared to second.